# Syntax highlighting changed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, colors, emacs

I recently switched from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. When using Emacs to edit Python code in the Terminal, my syntax highlighting looks very different in 16.04 compared to 15.10 (more shades of purple). This is true whether I'm using Emacs locally or ssh'ing to another computer, so it feels like something to do with the Terminal color scheme and not Emacs itself. I don't see anything in the new .bashrc file or Terminal preferences that would explain the difference, however.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `'TERM=xterm'` to my emacs alias solved the problem:

```
alias emacs='TERM=xterm; emacs -nw'
```

I'm not entirely sure why. Was inspired by this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236962/emacs-python-mode-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1):

By default Terminal uses the system colors palette.
You can change that at Edit > Profile Preferences > Colors (tab)

Comment: Fiddling with the terminal color preferences / schemes allows me to change the color of white text and colors seen in the command prompt, but not the highlight colors. If this issue didn't also affect highlighting via ssh I'd assume my emacs config was just different, but it feels more like a local Terminal issue.