# syntax highlighting in vi changed after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors, vi, syntax-highlighting

First, read this question below:

- [problem in terminal syntax highlighting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820074/syntax-highlighting-changed-in-ubuntu-16-04)

It also changed the default syntax highlighting in terminal after upgrading UBUNTU.

There is a difference between *ver.14* and *ver.16*. UBUNTU 14 uses gnome-terminal 3.6.2 while 16 takes higher a version of the terminal.

It's still the same configuration in terminal color settings, but different syntax highlighting.

.
Ubuntu 14.04:

[image: Ubuntu 14.04 version picture]

Ubuntu 16.04:

[image: Ubuntu 16.04 version picture]

Comment: @Zanna sorry for missing that. I use vi.

Comment: and you want the old highlighting back?

Comment: @Zanna Yes. exactly.

Comment: @Zanna and want to know what is the difference.

Comment: Never use vi, found [this]http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-colorscheme) though. HTH

Comment: Yup, @KwangilCho is using vim, as visible in the titlebar of the first screenshot. (On Ubuntu, `vi` is usually just a symlink to `vim`.) Making sure you're using the same vim color scheme is a good place to start. If they're the same on both, check the output of `echo $TERM` on both systems -- it's possible they're emulating different terminal types

Comment: @NickWeinberg Thank you. My desktop which is Ubuntu ver.16 uses xterm-256color. However my labtop which is Ubuntu ver.14 has xterm. Your recommendation is helpful to understand what is the difference.

Comment: You can adjust the TERM value manually: try starting vim with `TERM=xterm vim` or `TERM=xterm-256color vim`

Comment: @NickWeinberg Thanks Nick. I tried to change environment value by using `export TERM=xterm`, but they have same color config either xterm or xterm-256color

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Zanna Nope. I didn't. I just use the default settings that has been changed.